# Does magick fail with a single rolled 1?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

I am not sure if I understand the rules correctly how Magick actually works (Edit: in the 2nd Edition):

1. Tell what you want to do
2. Check if you know how to do this
3. Roll **as much dice as you wish** with the max. number of your current arete
4. Difficulty is **the highest sphere you actually use**, i.e. if you have matter 4 but only want to detect an element you roll against 1 (+3, +4 or +5 depending on the vulgarism of the effect)
5. Against the other WoD rules you do not fail when you roll more 1s than successes, but **you do fail in the moment when you roll a single 1**?

This seems not to be stated explicitly in the rules (at least in the German edition) but using all of your arete would not be risky if a single 1 would not result in a failure. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A single 1 will never botch unless you didn't roll any successes too.

1's generally count as anti-successes for the purpose of final roll resolution. However, botching depends a lot on the edition.

2nd Edition Mage the Ascension book specifically states on page 167:

> If the player botches the roll (rolls more 1's than successes)...

**In 2nd edition more 1's than successes is enough to botch a roll**. This caused botches to be very common when rolling against 8+ Difficulty. As Magic is often a very hard, it makes large Dice Pools and Extended Rolls a gamble - you are more likely to fail a roll due to 1's, and botch too.

The rule has been rectified in **Revised edition, where one success is enough to prevent a botch, regardless of the number of 1's rolled**. Here, botches are a lot less common, but still there is plenty of room for failure due to rolling multiple 1's.

So, specifically:

1. **Roll more successes than 1's** - your final result is a difference between successes and 1's, which is then compared to the Effect's required success number and can be a success or a failure depending on the effect.
2. **Roll as many successes as 1's** - it's a failure
3. **Roll more 1's than successes** - in 2nd edition it's a botch, in Revised it's a regular failure
4. **Roll (at least a single) 1 and no successes** - it's a botch.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with the statistics. You are totally right: The probability to roll a 1 stays the same with one or many dice, but the probabilty to roll more 1s than successes increases with the number of dice (given a certain difficulty).